# Problem with Date format in SOQL

Tags: apex, soql, datetime, date

I have a silly problem, when I pass Date from lightning input (type=date) i pass it as a string, 
and when i creating a query with this paramiter i recived error like below

> value of filter criterion for field 'StartDate' mu…of type date and should not be enclosed in quotes

So when i converted to Date type using **Date.parse** i recived error code

> Invalid date: 2020-03-12

But when i convert String to Date using **Date.valueOf**

> no viable alternative at character ''

here is my code

```
  if(!key.equals(START_DATE)) {
                        query += key + ' = ' + QUOTES + String.valueOf(inputMap.get(key)) + QUOTES + ' AND ';
                    }else{
                        startDate = Date.valueOf(inputMap.get(key));
                        query += key + ' = ' +startDate+ ' AND ';
                    }
```

And here's an example of the generated SOQL:

```
SELECT Id, AccountId ,CustomerSigned.Name, Name, Status, ContractNumber, Account.Name, Account.BillingCity, Education_Level__c, isActive__c, StartDate, ActivatedDate, EndDate, Category__c, Performance_Evaluation__c
    FROM Contract
    WHERE Account.Name = 'TestName' AND StartDate = 2020-03-12 00:00:00
```

Comment: Please add an example of what the generated query looks like and check the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm) for what a literal date value looks like.

Comment: >SELECT  Id, AccountId ,CustomerSigned.Name, Name, Status, ContractNumber, Account.Name, Account.BillingCity, Education_Level__c, isActive__c, StartDate, ActivatedDate, EndDate, Category__c, Performance_Evaluation__c FROM Contract WHERE Account.Name = 'TestName' AND StartDate = 2020-03-12 00:00:00

Comment: If at all possible you should generate your query using binding variables. If you can't do that you will need to ensure that you use escapeSingleQuotes for any user-originated data you insert into the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As can be seen from the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm), the required format for a date literal is:

> YYYY-MM-DD

To generate this, use:

```
startDate.format('yyyy-MM-dd')
```

As mentioned in the comments on your question, you also need to ensure you escape single quotes in any string values you insert into the query, since you are not using bindings (if you don't you are open to SOQL injection hacks):

```
String.escapeSingleQuotes(String.valueOf(inputMap.get(key)))
```